# Como centralizar o cabeçalho <th> de uma tabela HTML com css?

Tags: html5, css3

**Minha tabela:**

```
<table id="tabela">
    <th id="cabecalho" >Ação</th>
    <tr id = "linAcao" >    
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Acao.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <th id="cabecalho" >Comedia</th>
    <tr id = "linComedia">
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Comedia.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <th id="cabecalho" >Terror</th> 
    <tr id = "linTerror" > 
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Terror.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <th id="cabecalho" >Drama</th>
    <tr id = "linDrama" > 
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Drama.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <th id="cabecalho" >Romance</th>
    <tr id = "linRomance" > 
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Romance.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que está dando?

Comment: Seu HTML é inválido, `<th>` precisa estar dentro de uma `<tr>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como já mencionado pelo @Andorinha, antes de mais nada vamos trocar os `id`s por `class`:

```
...
<th class="cabecalho" >Ação</th>
...
<th class="cabecalho" >Comédia</th>
... etc
```

Apesar de a maioria dos browsers por padrão centralizarem os `th`, isto não é garantido que sempre vá acontecer (até por uma possível definição anterior em outro css). Assim, o ideal é acrescentar uma entrada explícita no `css` que garanta isso:

```
.cabecalho {text-align: center}
```

Answer (score 3):

Como o @bfavaretto disse no [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16877/como-centralizar-o-cabecalho-th-de-uma-tabela-html-com-css#comment31585_16877), corrigindo o html:

Resposta em visualização [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/7x8db/1/)

E também é inválido usar o id `cabecalho` para todos os `<th>` mude para class:

```
<table id="tabela">

    <tr id = "linAcao" >    
        <th class="cabecalho" >Ação</th>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Acao.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>


    <tr id = "linComedia">
        <th class="cabecalho" >Comedia</th>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Comedia.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>


    <tr id = "linTerror" > 
        <th class="cabecalho" >Terror</th> 
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Terror.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>


    <tr id = "linDrama" > 
        <th class="cabecalho" >Drama</th>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Drama.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>


    <tr id = "linRomance" > 
        <th class="cabecalho" >Romance</th>
        <td><a href="#"><img src="Romance.jpg" title=""/></a></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Veja o porque não usar o mesmo `ID` para vários elementos, aqui **[Class e Ids](http://desenvolvimentoparaweb.com/css/diferencas-entre-ids-e-classes/)**